# Pytest: Capturing multiple consecutive input prompts through capsys

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I would like to test python code with pytest. There I would like to both a return value of a function using user input (using monkeypatch) and the input prompts using capsys. However here there can be multiple input prompts in succession.

Example code (multiinput.py):

```py
def somefun():
    x = None
    while 'a' != x:
        x = input("prompt:")
    return x
```

As you can see, the while loop will forever continue until the lowercase letter `a` is passed by the user. Every time a prompt is issued in a new line.

The test file I tried looks like this (multiinput_test.py):

```py
from multiinput import somefun

def test_somefun(capsys, monkeypatch):
    
    # inputs
    user_inputs = iter(['b', 'c', 'a'])

    # expected
    prompt_expected =   "prompt:\n" + \
                        "prompt:\n" + \
                        "prompt:"
    return_expected = 'a'
    
    # Monkey patching
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: next(user_inputs))

    # test
    return_actual = somefun()
    cap = capsys.readouterr()

    # assert
    assert return_expected == return_actual
    assert cap.out == prompt_expected
```

Executing with:

```bash
pytest ./
```

The important bits from the log after executing pytest are

```
>       assert cap.out == prompt_expected
E       AssertionError: assert '' == 'prompt:\nprompt:\nprompt:'
E         - prompt:
E         - prompt:
E         - prompt:

multiinput_test.py:23: AssertionError
====================================================================================== short test summary info ======================================================================================= 
FAILED multiinput_test.py::test_somefun - AssertionError: assert '' == 'prompt:\nprompt:\nprompt:'
========================================================================================= 1 failed in 0.49s ==========================================================================================
```

This surprises me, because capsys only captured an empty string. When I do this with multiple prints (to stdout), then every `print()` is captured in a new line, just as I expect it. I would have expected this to happen similarly with the prompts in `input()`.

Maybe the user input would need to be also be put into the expected string like the following.

```py
# expected
prompt_expected =   "prompt:b\n" + \
                    "prompt:c\n" + \
                    "prompt:a"
```

But that is a separate issue that would be easily debugged.

Capturing just one invocation of `input()` in stdout through capsys works nicely. It's multiples that are posing an issue.

How can I test the prompts of multiple invocations of `input()` within one function run?